# How can I modify the .bbl generated when I use the cleanthesis template?

Tags: sorting, cleanthesis, bibliographystyle

I am using the cleanthesis template. For the bibliography, I use the options:

bibsys=bibtex
bibstyle=ieee,
bibsorting=nyt,

However, the references are not sorted by name. How can I sort them? Or, how can I can modify the .bbl to sort them? Any idea?

Comment: Please be more specific or show us exactly what references aren't sorted. Is this about the bibliography, display order in multi-citations or something else? Why do you think you need to change the .bbl file to achieve this? (This could be a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/397280))

Comment: In case you want to sort multi-citations: You need to pass `sortcites` to `biblatex`, see the first part of [my answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579274/92060)