# Sorting problem in cleanthesis

Tags: bibliographies, sorting, bibliographystyle, cleanthesis

I need your help about the order of citations of bibliography in cleanthesis. Specifically, I would like to show citations in the text sorted by year (e.g., BBB1990, CCC1995, AAA2000), but at the same time I would like to have in the bibliography citations sorted by name:

BIBLIOGRAPHY

- AAA2000
- BBB1990
- CCC1995

Cold you help me, please? Thanks!

Here below the settings concerning the problem:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{% setup clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    sansserif=false,%
    configurelistings=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    configurebiblatex=true,%
    bibsys=bibtex,%
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=authoryear,%
    bibsorting=ynt,%
}{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{cleanthesis}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by applying the solution of [Biblatex order of entries in a multi-citation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244971/biblatex-order-of-entries-in-a-multi-citation/247188#247188) to cleanthesis:

First we need to pass `sortcites` to `biblatex`. You can either add it directly in `cleanthesis.sty` or call `\PassOptionsToPackage{sortcites}{biblatex}` in your document before `cleanthesis` is loaded.

You already specified `bibsorting=ynt,` in your example so that should take care of sorting the multi-citations in your text by year.

Now go to your main tex file and find the relevant `\printbibliography` statement. We need to surround this with a `refcontext` to specify a different sorting order. This works for me:

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting=nyt]
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\end{refcontext}
```